# logging uncaught exceptions in Perl

Tags: perl, exception

I have a Perl web app and would like to log all uncaught exceptions (uneval'ed die's).  My first thought is to do something like this:

```
use Carp 'cluck';

sub main {
    my $logfile ="/some/path/logfile.txt";
    open STDERR, ">>$logfile";
    # main logic
    ...
}

sub eval_main {
   eval {
       main;
   };
   if ($@) {
       cluck $@;
       close STDERR;
       # redirect to "friendly error page"
       ....
   }
 }

 eval_main;
```

Is there a better way than this?

**EDIT:** Added redirect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler. See [%SIG in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25SIG):

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    open LOG, ">>my/error.log";
    print LOG @_;
    close LOG;
    print STDERR @_;
    exit 1;
};

sub main {
    ...
}

main();
```

Comment: This triggers on *caught* exceptions too; see the warnings in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%SIG and be sure to check $^S

Comment: Also please note that implemented this way it is very global and can be overriden by any other declaration in this manner. At least you should localize `$SIG{__DIE__}`. In many cases it is much easier to wrap main code in `eval` and report errors there.

Comment: @ysth... I looked at the description of $^S, but it's not clear to me how to use it... do you have any examples of how to check $^S in my situation?

Comment: `$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {confess "UNTRAPPED EXCEPTION:\n\t@_\n " unless $^S};`

Comment: @bvr The problem with the clean approach you suggest is that you can't get a stack dump from the point that triggered the exception.

Comment: @tchrist - you are right, thanks for point it out. I was considering just logging of error message.